# Sort a dictionary a value

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I know that this problem has been discussed, but none of the answers refer to a string as a key. I would like to sort a dictionary by a value - descending and ascending. Here are my sketches:

```
def ascending(d):
    from operator import itemgetter
    sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
    return d

f={'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'f': 5, 'e': 4}
g={'s': 3, 'y': 1, 'r': 7, 'h': 4}

print(hj(f))

def descending(d):
    from operator import itemgetter
    sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return d
print(jh(g))
```

However, I get:

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'f': 5, 'e': 4}
{'h': 4, 'r': 7, 'y': 1, 's': 3}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I improve the code?

OK, a little ask for explanation:
I have solved problem, using:

```
def ascending(d):
        from operator import itemgetter
        p=sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
        return p

    f={'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'f': 5, 'e': 4}
    g={'s': 3, 'y': 1, 'r': 7, 'h': 4}

    print(hj(f))

    def descending(d):
        from operator import itemgetter
        p=sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        return p
    print(jh(g))
```

How does sorted() works, if it doesn't affected d in 'return d'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: I have viewed this so-called 'duplicate' before asking and I don't know, what is so different in my solution that it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I have improved now.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but none of the answers refer to a string as a key.

That's not relevant.

> What am I doing wrong?

There is a big difference between [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) and [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). The 1st is evaluated for side effects, and returns `None`. The 2nd leaves its argument untouched, and creates a brand new list in sorted order.

```
    sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
    return d
```

You evaluated an expression (which did not change `d`), and then silently discarded the result. Then you returned the same old `d`.

You want to `return sorted( ... )` instead.

> How can I improve the code?

Thank you for asking, that's a terrific question! Do keep asking it of yourself.

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you put `import` statements at top of source file, please.